# R: How to find max length sequence between two values in a vector?

Tags: r

Let's say I want to find the longest length of consecutive numbers (excluding 0) in a sequence in R.

Example: `(0,2,3,0,5)` in this case it should return `2` .

The solution I came up with is as follows:

```
A1 <- c(1, 1, 0,1,1,1)  
length =NULL  
B<-rle(A1==0)  
C<-B$lengths  
D<-B$values  
for(i in 1:length(C)){  
if(D[i]==FALSE){length[i]=C[i]}
}

length <- length [!is.na(length )]  
max(length)  
[1] 3
```

How can I find the longest sequence of non-zero numbers in a vector in R?

Comment: `max(diff(which(A == 0)))-1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `rle`.  `A==0` output a logical index vector, `rle` computes the lengths and runs of values of adjacent elements that are the same for logical vector.  Extract the `lengths` of values that are not '0' and get the `max` after removing the first and last elements to account for the maximum lengths of non-zero elements at the start or end of vector.

```
 max(with(rle(A==0), lengths[-c(1, length(lengths))][
                     !values[-c(1, length(values))]]))
 #[1] 2
```

Another example

```
   A1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  max(with(rle(A1==0), lengths[-c(1, length(lengths))][
                      !values[-c(1, length(values))]]))
  #[1] 4
```

Or

```
 indx <- A1==0
 max(with(rle(A1[which(indx)[1L] : tail(which(indx),1)]==0), 
                   lengths[!values]))
#[1] 4
```

#### Update

Based on the new info, may be you can try,

```
 A1 <- c(1, 1, 0,1,1,1)  
 max(with(rle(A1==0), lengths[!values]))
 #[1] 3
```

Comment: FYI this is a valid answer, someone unhelpful tried to flag it was "low-quality"

Comment: @akrun nice solution as always. However, consecutive 0s should be taken care of : for `A <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0)` it gives 4.

Comment: @Khashaa You are right, I failed to check that condition.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Khashaa Your solution is very compact.  Why don't you add as an answer.  I couldn't beat its beauty :-)

Comment: @akrun I slightly prefer your solution because I think `rle(A==0)` is more operational than `which(A==0)`, and can give an answer to lots of other questions.

Comment: It's nice. But there is one problem if we have vector 
A=c(1,0,1,1,1) it breaks. Maybe I asked wrong, but this should be part of "longest length of consecutive numbers with no 0. So the answer should be 3 for this case.

Comment: @user2941942 I haven't checked all the possible scenarios.   May be it needs some fix for specific cases.

Comment: @user2941942 This was not the way I understand the question.  To me, it was  `I want to find max sequence(in length) between number 0`. ie. in the new vector, there is no between.  Only one 0 and then `1s` to the end.  So, my solution won't work.  You have to describe it correctly in the post though.

Comment: @akrun Yes. sorry. I only noticed this case just now.

Comment: @akrun Anyways, thanks a lot. You guys led me to right way(I think)

`length =NULL

B<-rle(A1==0)  

C<-B$lengths  
D<-B$values  
for(i in 1:length(C)){  
if(D[i]==FALSE){length[i]=C[i]}  
}  

length <- length [!is.na(length )]  
max(length)`

P.S I suck at formatting in this site.

Comment: @user2941942 No problem.  Glad to know it led to right way

Comment: @akrun Yes, of course. I also edited solution that covers exceptions if you want to check it out. Not pretty though, I am sure you would be more elegant ;)

Comment: @user2941942 I updated with an old version of my solution.  Check if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @user2941942 This was one of the codes I posted earlier.  But, then after Khashaa's comments, I thought that may not be the one you wanted.